# SQL - When value is not numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL and I'm looking up a reference number against a third table. What I'm try to get to is a syntax that says:

```
CASE
    WHEN NUM (TABLE 1) = NAME THEN LEFT(NUM (TABLE 1),14)
    WHEN NAME = ''UK'' THEN LEFT(NUM (TABLE 1),11)
    **** WHEN LEFT(NUM (TABLE 1), 3) IS NOT NUMERIC THEN LOOK FOR NUM IN TABLE 2*** 
    ELSE ACCGRPNUM
END AS ID,
```

I have inserted this (TABLE 1) to show where the two tables come into play.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put proper table schema. This looks more like algorithm when schema is not present.

Comment: Table definition would help to answer you question.

Comment: There are tons of reference if you just Google it.

Comment: What is `WHEN NUM (TABLE 1) = NAME` supposed to mean?   Is "NUM" supposed to be a function?  What would `NUM(TABLE 1)` return?

Comment: Built into the Case function are the column names, Num and Name are the column names. As mentioned above I just included the (Table1) to show which table each column refers to without writing out the whole code Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has an [ISNUMERIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) function. It should look something like this

```
WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(num, 3)) = 0 THEN ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this function is that the third character will not always be 0 it will vary. Which is why I'm trying to work out how to say if it is not numeric then...

Comment: ISNUMERIC(LEFT(value, 3)) returns 0 if the first (left-most) 3 characters of the string cannot be parsed into a numeric data type (int, float, decimal, etc.).